# Crop image, change black area if not not enough photo region in white

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have to crop a photo with python using PIL.
If the photo region is not enough, the rest of the area is colored in black.
How can I make that area white?

This is a part of the code I`m using now:

```
i = Image.open(filepath)
box2 = (newX,newY,newX+newW,newY+newH)
i2=i.crop(box=box2)
i2.load()
...
i2.save(new_filepath)
...
white=(255,255,255)
i3 = Image.new( 'RGB' , i2.size , white )
i3.paste( i2)
i3.save(filepath2,'PNG')
```

The crop works fine, but I want white instead of black in the rest of the area.
I tried creating a new image with white background and pasting the croped image, but it didn`t work.

EDIT:
example output

[image: example output]

EDIT2: I have the original image and the coords for the croping
**I updated the code**
Remeber that the crop coords can be negative.

Input & output example
input img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKb04.jpg

```
box2=(-743, 803, 1646, 4307)
```

output img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TMnZ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you can use numpy, you could do something like:

```
i22 = flipud(asarray(i2).copy())
# calculate the area that its black, using the original size and the box information
for i in xrange(blackrows):
  i22[i:] = asarray([255,255,255])
# and and something like that to the blackcolumns
```

I don't use PIL a lot, but it probably has some pixel acessing functions.

Comment: What if the image is already pure black ? This will not work in that case

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're doing something wrong, and that you should share your entire code, and the image.

I've done this many times in PIL , and the easiest solutions has always been to Paste the Crop onto an all-white image.

```
import Image

# open source
i = Image.open('hHncu.png')

# crop it
( newX , newY ) = ( 110 , 0 )
( newW , newH ) = ( 110 , 150 )
box_crop = ( newX,newY,newX+newW,newY+newH )
i2 = i.crop(box=box_crop)
i2.load()

# save it , just for testing
i2.save('hHncu-out.png')

# create the new image, and paste it in
# note that we're making it 300x300  and have the background set to white (255x3)
i3 = Image.new( 'RGB' , (300,300) , (255,255,255) )
# paste it at an offset. if you put no offset or a box, i3 must match i2s dimensions
i3.paste( i2 , (25,25) )
# save it
i3.save('hHncu-out-2.png')
```

Comment: I tried this solution first. I updated the code with this solution but no luck. I think its because after crop, the image already has the black area, and weh you copy/paste it on the new image, it copies it with the black area also. I aded input and output files.

Comment: The above code works as-is.  You're probably doing the crop wrong in your code.

Post a working example of the code that is causing an error so people can correct you.

Comment: the above code does not work when the crop area exceds the photo area. Try your code with this coords: # crop it
`( newX , newY ) = ( -100 , -100 )
( newW , newH ) = ( 400 , 250 )` and you will see the result

Comment: If you have more ideas, please share them.  The current code works only if the crop area does not exceeds the photo area. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Crap. I see.  I apologize for not fully understanding this.

This looks to be a bit of a bug / limitation on PIL -- it appears to be using 'black' as the default background color for the first image and including that background as part of the crop.  ( btw, this happens on positive and negative crops ).  

PIL doesn't seem to allow you to toggle the background color, and it doesn't look like it's treating this as an ALPHA channel ( though I could be wrong ).

For a long-term solution, I would contact the maintainer and request the ability to change bgcolor or treat it as an alpha...

Comment: For a short-term solution, I would just ensure that the bounding box for your crop is within the size of the image's bounding box.  If it's not, I'd crop the smaller amount and note the difference -- then offset your paste by that difference.

Comment: Or, use the same paste technique to pad out with white the source image before cropping. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly as you asked, convert the image to a numpy array and filter the full black rows and cols (on a second image). You can't simply make all the black pixels white, as this would affect those on the inside of the image.

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("hHncu.png") # Imgur's naming scheme
pix = numpy.array(img)        # Convert to array

black = numpy.array([0,0,0,255])
white = numpy.array([255,255,255,255])

pix2 = pix.copy()
dim  = pix.shape

for n in xrange(dim[0]):
    if (pix[n,:]==black).all(): 
        pix2[n,:,numpy.newaxis] = white

for n in xrange(dim[1]):
    if (pix[:,n]==black).all(): 
        pix2[:,n,numpy.newaxis] = white

# View the results
from pylab import *
subplot(121); imshow(pix )
subplot(122); imshow(pix2)
show()
```

[image]

It looks like there is some smoothing between the black and the image, a more advanced filter would be needed to fix this - but you can see how to get started from here!

Comment: What if I draw white rectangles over the black areas ? array operations sounds overkill. It`s for a web app so speed its an important factor.

Comment: You can certainly do so, but numpy is _designed_ for array operations and they are lightning fast, so I don't think it's a concern.

Comment: What if the image is already pure black ? This will not work in that case.

Comment: @Revelation If I give you as input to a program, an all black image, where do you suppose that I crop it at? If you've done that you need the original image dimensions as you've thrown some information away! This also holds if your org. image has a black border - these are edge cases that can be dealt with, IMO it would be easier to crop the _original_ image, but I was trying to answer the question as stated.

Comment: I have the original picture as you can see in the code. But i want after crop, white area instead of black. Thanks for your answer, and if you have more ideas, please share them.

Comment: @Revelation I don't see what you are looking for. In the example above, the black area on the border of the picture is turned white. Which, if I understand it, your black border area is the post-crop part that you want changed. A cropped image usually has _smaller_ dimensions than the original, do you intend to preserve the original image size with the white border?

Comment: I have an image as input. I crop an area that may exced the original size. The result I want is the croped area but with white extra area, instead of black. I use this for an image selector. The user can select an area of the pciture, even if its exced the photo region.

Comment: @Revelation The example above does exactly that --- if you can't articulate what is wrong with what I've given, I can't help you!

Comment: If the original image is pure black, it will not work. ( and this will happen for sure)

Comment: PIL will actually do this ( see my answer ). numpy is not needed.  The original poster is using Image wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ok.  so here's a quick stab at the idea i mentioned.

the rebox() function returns a 'fixed' bounding box, along with some offset data

this works in most situations.  i didn't integrate the offset data , but some version of it it would probably go in the `i3.paste` section.

the test image, grid.png is 300x300 and has blue lines at 50px, red lines at 150px and green lines at 200px.

you should be able to tweak this to your exact needs.

[image]

```
import Image
i1 = Image.open('grid.png')


DEBUG = True

def rebox( box_original , box_crop_desired ):

    box_crop_new= list( box_crop_desired )
    box_crop_offset = [ 0 , 0 ]

    if box_crop_desired[0] < 0:
        box_crop_new[0] = 0
        box_crop_offset[0] = box_crop_desired[0]

    if box_crop_desired[1] < 0:
        box_crop_new[1] = 0
        box_crop_offset[1] = box_crop_desired[1]

    if box_crop_desired[2] > box_original[2]:
        box_crop_new[2] = box_original[2]

    if box_crop_desired[3] > box_original[3]:
        box_crop_new[3] = box_original[3]

    box_crop_offset = tuple(box_crop_offset)
    box_crop_new = tuple(box_crop_new)

    if DEBUG :
        print "box_original                      %s" % str(box_original)
        print "box_crop_offset                   %s" % str(box_crop_offset)
        print "box_crop_desired                  %s" % str(box_crop_desired)
        print "box_crop_new                      %s" % str(box_crop_new)

    return ( box_crop_new , box_crop_offset )


( newX , newY ) = ( 200 , 200 )
( newW , newH ) = ( 400 , 400 )
box_crop_desired = ( newX , newY , newX+newW, newY+newH )
( box_crop , box_crop_offset ) = rebox( i1.getbbox() , box_crop_desired )

i2 = i1.crop(box=box_crop)
i2.save('grid-out-b.png')

i3 = Image.new( 'RGBA' , ( newW , newH ) , (255,255,255) )
i3.paste( i2 , (0,0) )
i3.save('grid-out-final-b.png')
```