# Background color when cropping image with PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

The good thing with [`PIL.crop`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) is that if we want to crop outside of the image dimensions, it simply works with:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
img.crop((-10, -20, 1000, 500)).save("output.jpg")
```

**Question: how to change the background color of the added region to white (default: black)?**

[image]

Note:

- if possible, I'd like to keep `crop`, and avoid to have to create a new image and paste the cropped image there like in [Crop image, change black area if not not enough photo region in white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177972/crop-image-change-black-area-if-not-not-enough-photo-region-in-white).
- Here is a download link to original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtA70.jpg (303x341 pixels)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it is not possible with one function call due to the relevant C function which seems to zero-out the destination image memory region (see it here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/libImaging/Crop.c#L47)

You mentioned as not interested to create new Image and copy over it but i am pasting that kind of solution anyway for reference:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
x1, y1, x2, y2 = -10, -20, 1000, 500  # cropping coordinates
bg = Image.new('RGB', (x2 - x1, y2 - y1), (255, 255, 255))
bg.paste(img, (-x1, -y1))
bg.save("output.jpg")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Basj Make sure not to edit someone else's answer. If you have an answer you can add it. Making drastic changes to other's answer is not ethical. Minor edits like spellings and title changes are fine. In your edit the intention of the OP was completely changed so it is better to add another answer.

Comment: @JeruLuke, the initial idea of sardok's answer is exactly kept in the edit (`bg = Image.new('RGB', ..., (255, 255, 255))`, then `bg.paste`). It is just a minor edit because my question was initially was about a border that was *the same* on top and on left. I just changed to conform to the question's (more general) current formulation.

Comment: @JeruLuke So it's not a new idea / new answer, just a slight modification. Also, it is now 100% working like it is (see output), that's why it's better to not change it to the initial state.

Comment: @Basj can't argue with that +1

Comment: Thank you @JeruLuke! (I already +1 yours too since a few days ;) )

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you intend to after using the `expand()` function  available in `ImageOps` module of PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
filename = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Maine_Coon_263.jpg'
img = Image.open(filename)

val = 10    #--- pixels to be cropped

#--- a new image with a border of 10 pixels on all sides
#--- also notice fill takes in the color of white as (255, 255, 255)
new_img = ImageOps.expand(img, border = val, fill = (255, 255, 255))

#--- cropping the image above will not result in any black portion
cropped = new_img.crop((val, val, 150, 150))
```

The `crop()` function only takes one parameter of how much portion has to be cropped. There is no functionality to handle the situation when a negative value is passed in. Hence upon passing a negative value the image gets padded in black pixels.

Using the `expand()` function you can set the color of your choice and then go ahead and crop as you wish.

### EDIT

In response to your edit, I have something rather naïve in mind but it works.

- Get the absolute values of all the values to be cropped. You can use `numpy.abs()`.
- Next the maximum among these values using `numpy.max()`.
- Finally expand the image using this value and crop accordingly.

This code will help you:

```
#--- Consider these values in a tuple that are to crop your image 
crop_vals = (-10, -20, 1000, 500)

#--- get maximum value after obtaining the absolute of each
max_val = np.max(np.abs(crop_vals))

#--- add border to the image using this maximum value and crop
new_img = ImageOps.expand(img, border = max_val, fill = (255, 255, 255))
cropped = new_img.crop((max_val - 10, max_val - 20, new_img.size[0], new_img.size[1]))
```

Comment: Good thinking !

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JeruLuke. My question was formulated in a specific case (border of 10 pixels on each side). I edited into a more general case (the black borders are different on each side), how would you deal with this general case?

Comment: 'padded in black pixels' is not quite the right description. The image data for 'extra' pixels is set to zero. For RGB(A) images, that means those pixels are black. For palette images, it's whatever colour was assigned to position `0` in the palette.

Comment: We're close @JeruLuke, but it gives this as output: https://imgur.com/a/92UFOeS ;)

Comment: @Basj There was a small miscalculation. See the update again

Comment: Thank you @JeruLuke. It still does not give the right format: https://imgur.com/a/ZvijjZ7. I'll have a look in the next days.